# Facebook page's status updates

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK 3. How can I get the public status of a special page in Facebook without authentication? How can I put a list of all of a Facebook page's status updates in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want by the facebook graph. Go and read out the documentaion for the paging section. you will find out the answer.!!

heres the link, This may help.: [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)